# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 after install Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have such a problem. 
I used Xcode 3.2.5 earlier then I have installed 4.1 Xcode into Developer folder, so my Xcode 3.2.5 was automatically removed to Xcode 3.2.5 folder. So I was a happy iOs developer with 2 Xcodes. But then I decided to install Xcode 4.2( into Developer folder too). First time no any Xcode could be launched. After reboot everything became ok. Except this:

```
CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTest.app
```

cd /Users/alexslabinsky/Desktop/MyTest
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Alex Slabinsky (NUMBERS_here)" --resource-rules=/Users/alexslabinsky/Desktop/MyTest/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTest.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/alexslabinsky/Desktop/MyTest/build/MyTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTest.build/MyTest.xcent /Users/alexslabinsky/Desktop/MyTest/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTest.app

/Users/alexslabinsky/Desktop/MyTest/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyTest.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I tried almost all what could find here and by Google.com but nothing helps. Please, help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally had upgrade issues several times in relation to using XCode 4.x, where the only thing that solved my problems was to completely uninstall the existing Dev Tools, reboot, and then install the new ones. Uninstall is done via:

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: That did not help. Very sorry.

Comment: Sorry. Have you tried reinstalling your certs? Another thing might be to 'modernize' your project settings inside XCode.